# how to get kendo generated node list in kendo-treeview

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treeview, kendo-angular-ui

In the kendo tree view using angular, how to get a list with their respective item detail in .ts file after rendering the kendo tree view component.
required list as below
["0","0_1","0_2","0_1_1"]